# Adjust blockquote so it fits both short and long quotes

Tags: html, css, block

My blockquote and cite code looks and works well for shorts quotes (see the Albert Einstein quote), but when my quote gets too long (see the Bill Gates quote), the end quote doesn't move to the very end of the block.

How do I style it so no matter how long my quote is the end quote mark will always be at the end of the quote?

See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3PTtv/85/

```
<blockquote>The world is a dangerous place to live; not because of the people who are evil, but because of the people who don't do anything about it. <cite>Albert Einstein</cite> 
</blockquote>
<br>
<blockquote>I actually thought that it would be a little confusing during the same period of your life to be in one meeting when you're trying to make money, and then go to another meeting where you're giving it away. I mean is it gonna erode your ability, you know, to make money? Are you gonna somehow get confused about what you're trying to do? <cite>Bill Gates</cite>
</blockquote>

blockquote {
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: italic;
width: 500px;
margin: 0.25em 0;
padding: 0.25em 40px;
line-height: 1.45;
position: relative;
color: #232323;
margin:0 auto;
display:block;
width:60%;
}

blockquote:before {
display: block;
content: "\201C";
font-size: 80px;
position: absolute;
left: -20px;
top: -20px;
color: #f66511;
}

blockquote cite {
color: #616161;
font-size: 14px;
display: block;
margin-top: 5px;
}

blockquote cite:before {
content: "\2014 \2009";
}

blockquote:after {
display: block;
content: "\201D";
font-size: 80px;
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
top: 40px;
color: #f66511;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `top: 40px` with `bottom: -50px` for `blockquote:after`. This way the ending quote has the same distance from the bottom of the quote, no matter how long it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/3PTtv/86/

Answer (score 0):

Change from `top` to `bottom` in `blockquote:after` and it will position the ending quote better. Also the line height could be adjusted rather than using `-20px`.

`blockquote:after {
  bottom: -20px;
  display: block;
  content: "\201D";
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  color: #f66511;
}`